# DynamoDBLocal in sbt dependencies

Tags: maven, sbt, dynamo-local

I've added `"com.amazonaws" % "dynamodb-titan100-storage-backend" % "1.0.0"` to my dependencies and the build broke because of `com.amazonaws#DynamoDBLocal;[1.10.5.1, 2.0.0): not found`. I've fixed this by adding mavenLocal resolver(I have built dynamodb-titan100-storage-backend localy earlier) but it is not the best solution, I think.

dynamodb-titan100-storage-backend has additional repository called "AWS DynamoDB Local Release Repository" in pom.xml pointing to `http://dynamodb-local.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/release` but adding it as sbt resolver doesn't fix the problem.

My question is: why this repostiry works with maven but does not with sbt?

[Link to pom.xml](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-titan-storage-backend/blob/1.0.0/pom.xml)

Part of sbt log:

```
[info] Resolving com.amazonaws#DynamoDBLocal;[1.10.5.1, 2.0.0) ...
[warn]  module not found: com.amazonaws#DynamoDBLocal;[1.10.5.1, 2.0.0)
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/wpitula/.ivy2/local/com.amazonaws/DynamoDBLocal/[revision]/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== fedora: tried
[warn]   file:/usr/share/sbt/ivy-local/com.amazonaws/DynamoDBLocal/[revision]/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/DynamoDBLocal/[revision]/DynamoDBLocal-[revision].pom
[warn] ==== sonatype-snapshots: tried
[warn]   https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/amazonaws/DynamoDBLocal/[revision]/DynamoDBLocal-[revision].pom
[warn] ==== DynamoDbLocal: tried
[warn]   http://dynamodb-local.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/release/com/amazonaws/DynamoDBLocal/[revision]/DynamoDBLocal-[revision].pom
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12.1 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.amazonaws#DynamoDBLocal;[1.10.5.1, 2.0.0): not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was likely in a wrong type of the SBT resolver. You should use a [Maven-repository resolver](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Resolvers.html#Maven) like this:

```
resolvers += "DynamoDBLocal" at "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dynamodb-local/release"
```