# AWS Lambda + Tinkerpop/Gremlin + TitanDB on EC2 + AWS DynamoDB in cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, gremlin, tinkerpop3

I am trying to execute following flow:

1. user hits AWS Gateway (REST),
2. it triggers AWS Lambda,
3. that uses Tinkerpop/Gremlin connects to
4. TitanDB on EC2, that uses
5. AWS DynamoDB in cloud (not on EC2) as backend.

Right now I have managed to crete fully working TitanDB instance on EC2, that stores data in DynamoDB in cloud.
I am also able to connect from AWS Lambda to EC2 through Tinkerpop/Gremlin BUT only this way:

```
Cluster.build()
       .addContactPoint("10.x.x.x") // ip of EC2
       .create()
       .connect()
       .submit("here I type my query as string and it will work");
```

And this works, however I strongly prefer to use "Criteria API" (GremlinPipeline) instead of plain Gremlin language.
In other words, I need ORM or something like that.
I know, that Tinkerpop includes it.
I have realized, that what I need is object of class Graph.
This is what I have tried:

```
Graph graph = TitanFactory
            .build()
            .set("storage.hostname", "10.x.x.x")
            .set("storage.backend", "com.amazon.titan.diskstorage.dynamodb.DynamoDBStoreManager")
            .set("storage.dynamodb.client.credentials.class-name", "com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain")
            .set("storage.dynamodb.client.credentials.constructor-args", "")
            .set("storage.dynamodb.client.endpoint", "https://dynamodb.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com")
            .open();
```

However, it throws "Could not find implementation class: com.amazon.titan.diskstorage.dynamodb.DynamoDBStoreManager".
Of course, computer is correct, as IntelliJ IDEA also cannot find it.

My dependencies:

```
//
// aws
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-core:+'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-events:+'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-log4j:+'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-dynamodb:1.10.5.1'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-ec2:+'
//
// database
// titan 1.0.0 is compatible with gremlin 3.0.2-incubating, but not yet with 3.2.0
compile 'com.thinkaurelius.titan:titan-core:1.0.0'
compile 'org.apache.tinkerpop:gremlin-core:3.0.2-incubating'
compile 'org.apache.tinkerpop:gremlin-driver:3.0.2-incubating'
```

What is my goal: have fully working Graph object

What is my problem: I don't have DynamoDBStoreManager class, and I do not know what dependency I have to add.

My additional question is: why connecting through Cluster class requires only IP and works, but TitanFactory requires properties like those I have used on gremlin-server on EC2?
I do not want to create second server, I just want to connect as client to it and take Graph object.

EDIT:
After adding resolver, it builds, in output I get multiple:

13689 [TitanID(0)(4)[0]] WARN  com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.idmanagement.ConsistentKeyIDAuthority  - Temporary storage exception while acquiring id block - retrying in PT2.4S: com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.TemporaryBackendException: Wrote claim for id block [1, 51) in PT0.342S => too slow, threshold is: PT0.3S

and execution hangs on open() method, so does not allow me to execute any queries.

Comment: **For a Graph DB ORM consider using Ferma**. It provides an ORM / OGM layer and may be exactly what you need. Supports Titan too.

https://github.com/Syncleus/Ferma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `DynamoDBStoreManager` class, you would need this [dependency](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-titan-storage-backend/blob/1.0.0/pom.xml#L3-L5):

```
compile 'com.amazonaws:dynamodb-titan100-storage-backend:1.0.0'
```

Then for the DynamoDBLocal issue, try adding this resolver:

```
resolvers += "AWS DynamoDB Local Release Repository" at "http://dynamodb-local.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/release"
```

I'm not entirely clear on what this means -- *"Criteria API" instead of plain Gremlin language*. I'm guessing that you mean that you want to interact with the graph using Java rather than passing Gremlin as a string over to a running Titan/Gremlin Server? If this is the case, then you don't need to start a Titan/Gremlin Server at all (step 4 above). Write an AWS Lambda program (step 2-3 above) that creates a direct Titan client connection via `TitanFactory`, where all of the Titan configuration properties are for your DynamoDB instance (step 5 above).

Comment: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
> Could not find any matches for com.amazonaws:DynamoDBLocal:[1.10.5.1, 2.0.0) as no versions of com.amazonaws:DynamoDBLocal are available.
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/DynamoDBLocal/maven-metadata.xml
      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/DynamoDBLocal/
  Required by:
      [my application] > com.amazonaws:dynamodb-titan100-storage-backend:1.0.0

Comment: I am basically getting this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35240114/dynamodblocal-in-sbt-dependencies

Comment: By "Criteria API" I mean what is now (after Apache took project) known as GremlinPipeline - so traveling through graph using java syntax instead of queries in strings (like JPQL vs Criteria API).

Comment: did you try adding the AWS DynamoDB Local Release Repository? https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-titan-storage-backend/blob/1.0.0/pom.xml#L311-L320